# The difference between 'I love him' and 'I am in love with him'

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between 'being in love with' someone and 'loving' someone, as in these two sentences?

> 1. I love him.
> 2. I am in love with him.

Comment: There are plenty of discussions online about this. I don't guarantee that they are any good! https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=in+love+versus+love

Comment: As Parthian suggests, "I love him" can be used, with qualification, to mean a non-romantic form of love.  Absent qualification, however, the two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Being in love with someone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31937/being-in-love-with-someone)

Answer (score 1):

"In love" implies a romantic (non-Platonic) attraction to / affection for (usually) a person.

If you simply say you love someone, that's different. It could imply any number of things depending on context, but it doesn't necessarily imply romantic attraction. However, it can be construed that way, so it's usually important to give additional context if you don't mean it romantically (e.g. "I love him like a brother").